# How many pencils are there?

Tags: probability

Four pencils are chosen (without replacement) from a pencil case, two of which are blunt. The probability that both blunt pencils are chosen is twice the probability that neither is chosen. How many pencils are
there in the pencil case?

Comment: Why the close vote? Too simple?

Comment: Sorry, but this sort of basic maths problem is [off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/5373).

Comment: @Randal'Thor I thought it was silly enough to be a puzzle :-/  I can't delete it now in any case.

Comment: The “color” aspects - pencils instead of balls from an urn, say - don’t really change what type of a puzzle something is, though. There’s no real clever insight needed here, just plugging the proper formulas together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are

> seven pencils.

Let $n$ be the number of sharp pencils, then

> we know that $\binom n2=2\binom n4$. This is satisfied for $n=5$ where $\binom 52=10$ and $\binom n4=5$.

Comment: Very nice and very fast!